# how to build libwebsocket library (Socket programming) and integrate in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, sockets

I googled lot, but did not get any information. I want step by step procedure to compile and build libwebsocket library for iOS app .Please give me some solution.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS you don't have a lot of implementations of websocket, the main is [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) and you can install it with [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) which is the main tool used to install libs easily.
I suggest you take a look at these things.

Comment: I need to integrate only libwebsocket. Please tell me step by step guide of how to build libwebsocket using cmake and toolchain.I did googled but did not understand.